# PowerShell Asynchronous Zip for Windows Server 2008

Tags: powershell, asynchronous, zip, windows-server-2008, windows-server-2008-r2

I need to run a PowerShell script that zips larger files (dozens of gigabytes) asynchronously on Windows Server 2008 virtual machines without using 3rd parties. Is that possible and how?

Comment: Have you tried anything yourself yet? Without using 3rd party tools, I don't think it is possible since `Compress-Archive` has a maximum file size of 2 GB..

Comment: I am trying with TAR despite it being added on Windows 10, but seems it is not working. The situation about 3rd parties is that the VM has its policies about that, even about connectivity. I actually found the possibility using 7Zip4PowerShell, don't know about the support for bigger files thou.